# SELECT inside SELECT in Redshift

Tags: select, redshift

```
select
  t.col1,
  t.col2,
  a.col1,
  b.somecolumn
  VQ.a,
  VQ.b,
  VQ.e,
  VQ.d,
  VQ.f,  
  (select
      t.status as a,
      p.id as b,
      p.permit as c,
      p.des as d,
      p.error_code as e,
      p.cause as f
   from table_A t 
   inner join table_B p on t.a = p.a 
   where p.c = 'license' and t.status = 'Fail'
  ) as VQ
from table_A t 
join table_C a on t.col1 = a.asset_id 
join table_b b on t.somecolumn = b on somecolumn;
```

When I execute the above code, I encounter the error

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: navigation on column "vq" is not allowed as it is not SUPER type
```

I am trying to do a select inside select.

Comment: You can't use a whole `select` inside another one, unless it is a single value. And it's anyway rather strange, as the subquery is not correlated to the outer query. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to get a table with all the values. joining table A and B based on a condition and combining with the remaining columns from the other join

Comment: I don't get how you want to do that, given that you are not correlating it. A cross-join? Perhaps you just need another join to `table_B` on the outer query and remove the subquery completely. Sample data and expected results would help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select
  t.col1,
  t.col2,
  a.col1,
  b.somecolumn
  VQ.a,
  VQ.b,
  VQ.e,
  VQ.d,
  VQ.f  
FROM (select
      t.status as a,
      p.id as b,
      p.permit as c,
      p.des as d,
      p.error_code as e,
      p.cause as f
   from table_A t 
   inner join table_B p on t.a = p.a 
   where p.c = 'license' and t.status = 'Fail'
  ) as VQ
, table_A t 
join table_C a on t.col1 = a.asset_id 
join table_b b on t.somecolumn = b on somecolumn;
```

or something like that, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

We can't select FROM a table that doesn't live in the FROM part of the query.

Current, table VQ lives inside of a single row of the results. So the rest of the query cannot select from it.

One solution would be to refactor and move your VQ table into the FROM section of the query as needed.

EDIT: Additionally, we cannot select multiple fields back into a single row. So yes, this query is broken in multiple ways.